# IF and && statements with Dates

Tags: powerbi, dax

Needed help where I have a table with 2 date columns and a status column, I am trying to return a value based on the condition that if both dates are equal and status is "resolved" then return a text value saying "resolved on the same day" or keep it blank

I have created a new column in my table where I am trying to see if Date1 = Date2 and status is complete then return 'resolved on the same day' else return blank. I am sure I am going wrong somewhere as I am new to this, any help would be much appreciated.

```
Column1= IF('ALL CASES'[Date1] = 'ALL CASES'[Date2] && 'ALL CASES'[Status]="Resolved","Resolved on the same day")
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the result when you use your formula in a **calculated column**:

[image]